# TypeScript Electron Js , React Js and Forge : problem when i build the app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, electron, electron-forge

I am trying to create a simple application. when I'm in development, ( npm start) I correctly display the image in .svg

But when I build the app, it doesn't find the image for me.

[here is the picture after construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmqnr.png)
[[here is the picture in development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D92T1.png)

I have created a resources folder and added this code:

webpack.plugins

```
import type IForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin';
import CopyPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin: typeof IForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

export const plugins = [
  new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
    logger: 'webpack-infrastructure',
  }), 
  new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
      { from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', "images"), to: path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack/renderer', "images") },
    ],
  })
];
```

and import svg file :

```
import React from "react";
export default class Acceuil extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="container_title">
                        <h1>Figrou tiktok bot</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="text_container">
                        <input type="text" className="input" id="username" placeholder="username" />
                        <img src="./images/send.svg" alt="connect" className="send" id="connect" height="35vh" title="se connecter"/>
                        <i id="info-connection"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a pretty cool library called react-native-svg , feel free to check it out . it allows you to correctly compile an svg file into a react component.